# Flutter don't recognize ANDROID_HOME neither ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, linux, flutter

I installed [android-sdk](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-sdk/) and [flutter-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/flutter-git/) on Manjaro with AUR. I set and exported the vars ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT === /opt/android-sdk.

However, when I run `flutter doctor` the android sdk seems to not been recognized.

I will use flutter on vs-code.

How can I set up all this correctly?

[image]

What I did:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk/`

`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk/`

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-4.0.pre.75, on Linux, locale
    en_CA.UTF-8)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android
      SDK components.
      (or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setu
      p for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
      ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: How did you set your ANDROID_HOME variable and where?

Comment: Editted it. On ~/.zshrc and directly on terminal

Comment: also set it to .bashrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was the jdk version, I was using version 10. The recommend one is version 8 because the java.se.ee class.

**Steps**

Use this command or use the "Add/Remove Softare"

`yaourt -S flutter-bin android-sdk android-sdk-platform-tools`

Choose the open jdk 8 and run all commands below:

1. `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/*`
2. `flutter precache && flutter doctor`

If "Android Licenses are unkown", run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

These steps will automatically set all env vars such as "ANDROID_HOME" but if you get any error, export them using the path to android-sdk, that will be `/opt/android-sdk/`

Answer (score 0):

Run Android Studio, create a new project and run it

Comment: I don't want to install and run Android Studio. There's another way?

Comment: Android Studio is the easiest way to fix this problem after that you can uninstall android studio

Comment: well, this is so messy, but ok

Comment: So, when I uninstalled Android Studio, this is the output for flutter doctor: 

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
    version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setu
      p for detailed instructions.